# React Native Global Object With Separate Files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a new React Native app that right now has everything in one file. In the name of reducing technical debt and increased modularity, I would like to begin moving each of my several screen components to separate files. The issue is that there is some state (user data) and functions (networking, persistent data) that are global and used on various screens through out my App.

Due to this, I am unable to both move my screen code to separate files and leverage global state throughout my application:

```
var globalState = {
  val: "Default",
}

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View></View>
    )
  }
  someFunction = () => {
    Alert.alert(globalState.val);
  }
}

class LoginScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View></View>
    )
  }

  someFunction = () => {
    globalState.val = "Something";
  }
}
```

Basically, I want access to globalState from both screens but have them in a separate file. I want each screen to *share* the globalState object so that one screen can update information and have the other screen access that information.

I would like to solve this without using any additional libraries like Redux.

Comment: If there are only few children component then you can simply pass the data as `props`. If not then use `redux` to share data between multiple components

Comment: I would prefer a solution that doesn't add complexity, both of those solutions make my code more complicated yet would simply be solving a problem that I have already solved. @MilindAgrawal

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to use a global state management solution like Redux or Mobx instead, or use something like React's Context api, or the useContext hook.

Comment: I would like a solution that does not require me to pass a context object constantly, and that does not require an additional library. The entire point is avoiding the additional complexity that comes with Redux. Its very easy for me to use my globalState object as it is, is there no solution that allows me to simply share an object across files?